# Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace all occurrences in the document from:

```
to_date(xxx)
```

to

```
sysdate
```

`xxx` is the varying string in all lines.

Can someone help? Thanks

I tried using the regex command but was unable to get the desired result. Is there any better way.

Comment: Can `xxx` contain closing parentheses?

Comment: @knittl _"Wow, two ChatGPT answers to a single question"_ - it's only going to get worse. Stack Overflow (the company) just _loves_ AI and _hates_ that their moderators are trying to do something about it.

Comment: @knittl no 'xxx' does not have closing parenthesis. Do you have a solution for this. Chatgpt sucks lol

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Just need to search for `to_date\([^)]+\)` and replace with `sysdate` in notepad++.

Thanks